# Prevent duplicates from json array with reactjs and axios

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, axios

***Look at my comments below the conversation with @Akrion who helped me fix this to see the solution!!!!***

I'm really new to reactJS and axios both but was trying something with a classmate earlier and now I'm stuck. I want to render the "sport"-categories from the json-file, but the same categories shows up several times. What is a good practice to sort away the duplicates so that only e.g. "Football" shows up once?

Sorry, again, new to this. I've been trying some stuff like Javascript functions to sort it... but I'm just unsure where to put the code and I keep going in circles. Let me know if anything that I said is confusing (English is not my first language). Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class SportsList extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://json-file.json')
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        posts: res.data
      })
    })  
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    const { posts } = this.state;
    const postList = posts.length ? (
        posts.map(post => {
          return (
            <div key={post.id}>
              <div>
                {post.sport}
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })
      ) : (
        <div>No Sports Available</div>
      )
    return (
      <div> 
      {postList}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SportsList;
```

Comment: Use `Set` rather than basic Array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also simply group by your post id via `Array.reduce` and then get the values. Change your `render` to this:

```
render() {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    const uniquePosts = Object.values(posts.reduce((r,c) => { 
      r[c.id] = c 
      return r
    }, {}))
    const postList = uniquePosts.length ? (
        uniquePosts.map(post => {
          return (
            <div key={post.id}>
              <div>
                {post.sport}
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })
      ) : (<div>No Sports Available</div>)
    return (<div>{postList}</div>);
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't gotten to good at understanding the errors yet, but I get a:

  ./src/components/SportsList.js
  Line 19:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  17 |         render() {
  18 |           const { posts } = this.state;
> 19 |           const uniquePosts = Object.values(posts.reduce(r,c) => (r[c.id] = c,r), {})
     |                                                               ^
  20 |           const postList = uniquePosts.length ? (
  21 |               uniquePosts.map(post => {
  22 |                 return (

Comment: I think it's missing a closing bracket for "Object.values(" which I guess is going on the end of the line? I still get all the duplicates though if I place it there.

Comment: Sorry: dubs?
uniquePosts is fetching all of the existing matches it looks like. And then I get: "Line 18:  Unexpected use of comma operator  no-sequences on the:  " 'c,r), {}))'

Comment: Ah of course sorry. It's a bit late here...I tried it. Still get all the duplicates.

Comment: See this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/akrion/2nLkhgxf/ Something else is wrong. The unique logic works as expected.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will play around with it and see what I can find. Probably some stupid mistake somewhere. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Looked at your fiddle once more today. Wrote it in my editor and changed the data around a little and then I realised when looking at "r[c.id] = c " I just had to change "id" to "sport" instead. Working now. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 4):

You should ideally fix the data on the server-side, but you can remove duplicates front-end also:

```
res.data.reduce((acc, post) => {
  const post1 = acc.find(x => x.sport === post.sport);
  if (!post1) {
    acc.push(post1);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Not the most efficient method, but it's simple

Comment: @Joel8bitar Use this in your setState: `this.setState({ posts })`, where `posts` is the returned value from the function call above

Comment: So only replace it with the line that says: "res.data" after "posts:" ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use reduce for filter sports before render, for example before setState

```
const sportsFiltered = sports.reduce((accum, sport) => {
    const accumulator = [...accum];
    if(!accumulator.some(item => item.id === sport.id)) {
        accumulator.push(sport);
    }
    return accumulator;
},[]);

class SportsList extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://json-file.json')
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        posts: sportsFiltered(res.data)
      })
    })  
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    const { posts } = this.state;
    const postList = posts.length ? (
        posts.map(post => {
          return (
            <div key={post.id}>
              <div>
                {post.sport}
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })
      ) : (
        <div>No Sports Available</div>
      )
    return (
      <div> 
      {postList}
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Right after the `render() {  ` ?
I only get "sports is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

```
const newPosts = [...new Set(posts)]
```